# Trouble running httparty in rails 4.0 with ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, httparty

To include httparty in my rails 4.0.0 app, in my gemfile I wrote:

```
gem 'httparty'
```

and then ran `bundle install`

Next in my `application.rb` file, I inserted this:

```
module myApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ### ---
    config.gem "httparty"
    ### ---
end
```

Now when I load `rails c` and do a `require "httparty"`, I get `false`

What am I doing wrong? How do I load httparty in my rails app?

Comment: But does it work? I can `require 'nokogiri'` from `irb` and get `true`, `require 'set'` says `false` but they both work. And both `require`s say false from the Rails console but they both still work there too.

Comment: Sorry it does work - was using the caps wrong -eeps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already loaded by Rails. You also don't need the config.gem in application.rb

Try using HTTParty from the console. It should just work.

Comment: might start owing you beermoney on SO - please open tab